# What does npm mean for socket.io/installing stuff?

Tags: node.js, installation, socket.io, npm

I'm a real noob at this. I've just began scratching the surface on node.js/socket.io/html5 and stuff. I finally figured out how to use my command prompt (using windows) to launch a "hello world" application with the command "node example.js." But what does `npm` mean? When I'm looking at socket.io it says to install, `npm install socket.io` Does that mean I need to extract all the files into my nodejs folder?

I'm confused.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=npm It's the first result. Next time try a Google search? ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

npm is a command line interface program to manage node.js libraries (it stands for node package manager - at least [it did initially](https://github.com/npm/cli/commit/4626dfa73b7847e9c42c1f799935f8242794d020#diff-04c6e90faac2675aa89e2176d2eec7d8R1), they since turned this into a [bit of a running gag](https://github.com/npm/npm-expansions) - thanks to @spex in the comments for that link). [Check out the docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/), it is awesome and amazing. As you mentioned, just type npm install  in a command prompt, and voilà, you have the library in your local node modules.

Comment: This link no longer points to the docs. Consider updating? Nowhere on the npm site does it say that it stands for "node package manager"

Comment: "npm" does not stand for "node package manager." See: https://web.archive.org/web/20150216184318/https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/faq#if-npm-is-an-acronym-why-is-it-never-capitalized And: https://github.com/npm/npm-expansions

Comment: Of course it's "cooler" if it's not such a boring acronym, and they "marketed" heavily to move away from that since, but the humour in that page you linked is pretty obvious. There are hints that show that it was indeed the meaning, originally (as linked from the wikipedia npm page): https://github.com/npm/cli/commit/4626dfa73b7847e9c42c1f799935f8242794d020#diff-04c6e90faac2675aa89e2176d2eec7d8R1

Answer (score 17):

**npm** is a generally awesome program for managing packages and dependencies (especially while you have a network connection). It does lots of [fancy things](http://blog.izs.me/post/1675072029/10-cool-things-you-probably-didnt-realize-npm-could-do) and is most commonly used with node.js projects.  That said, it's an unfortunately common misconception that the acronym stands for "node package manager".

In reality, **npm** doesn't *actually* stand for anything as it's not an acronym. With taglines like ["no problem, meatbag"](https://twitter.com/npmjs/status/347062349540237312) the npm organization playfully resists the trend of acronymization. It should always be referenced in lowercase to avoid confusion with the [National Association of Pastoral Musicians](http://npm.org).

Answer (score 1):

**npm** is stands for **Non-Parametric Mapping** utility written by *Chris Rorden*...

But we can keep it as `Node Package Manager` and it is very helpful for  Module Loader which uses CommmonJS module pattern, and I am not sure will Node will support the ES2015 Module Loading Syntax (Built in module Loading Syntax)?

Answer (score -2):

for those who are wondering the same thing, you just type `npm install socket.io` in the command prompt where nodejs file is.

`C:/Program Files/nodejs`

That should be what your command prompt should say and then just type that in.

Comment: Actually that should just be in your path. You want to install most npm packages in the actual directory of the project, so it can create a local node_modules directory there.