# How to install `yeoman` latest version?

Tags: node.js, npm, yeoman

I installed the `node` as new version. once i installed i checked in `cmd` for like this:

```
C:\Users\Mohamed.Arif>node --version && npm --version
v0.10.35
1.4.28
```

But after I installed the `node, npm` I am trying to install the latest `yeoman`. in their website, i noted the `npm` version requires `v2.1.0+` - i confused here. how to i install the `npm` as they requested?

I am running the latest version of `node` only.

Install prerequisites

```
Before installing Yeoman, you will need the following:

Node.js v0.10.x+
npm (which comes bundled with Node) v2.1.0+
git
You can check if you have Node and npm installed by typing:
```

http://yeoman.io/codelab/setup.html

What is wrong here? I am working with `windows7`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try `npm install -g npm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [How do I update npm on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26908899/how-do-i-update-npm-on-windows)

tl;dr - npm -g install npm does work, but the old version of npm is still in your PATH.

```
Option 3: navigate to C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs with cmd.exe and then run     
the installation without -g:

npm install npm
```