# Issue when using npm Windows Upgrade

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, powershell, npm

I've been trying to update npm on windows and found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26908899/how-do-i-update-npm-on-windows#) which provided a solution where the following commands were supposed to be run:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser -Force
npm install -g npm-windows-upgrade
npm-windows-upgrade
```

The first command executes seemingly correctly, but when I try running the second one, I get this [log](https://gist.github.com/loremIpsum1771/2aca05f5bea5bf3a79e2b51f6ff03276) which seems to indicate that a version of windows upgrade needs to be specified. So I then ran:
`npm install -g npm-windows-upgrade 6.9.1` and got this [error log](https://gist.github.com/loremIpsum1771/d219631318e9ef56c3d647f325a06ae0)

Of course when the last command of `npm-windows-upgrade` is run, I get the error that it isn't recognized. The other [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26908899/how-do-i-update-npm-on-windows#)  had a solution for either removing both of these files:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\npm
C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\npm.cmd
```

or

running this command in an elevated powershell:

```
npm install npm@latest
```

As I don't have admin rights (and can't really acquire them) on my computer and given that both of these options require admin rights, how can I go about upgrading node.js on Windows?

Answer (score 2):

i never did use npm-windows-upgrade but it seam like you need to run cmd as administration 
otherwise i recommande using [n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n)
Run cmd as adminstrator and install [n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n) using :

```
> npm install -g n
```

then Upgrade or install the latest official release using :

```
> n latest
```

Upgrade or install the stable official release using :

```
> n stable
```

Upgrade or install the latest LTS official release:

```
> n lts
```

Comment: I tried installing n but got this [error log] (https://gist.github.com/loremIpsum1771/20b52a1fd26df221ed5cc9eaf4ac155c)

Comment: you need to run cmd as administrator , if the problem doesn't solve then you have probably proxy or firewall problem if so check this issue [link](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/8048)