# npm update cant change version

Tags: node.js, typescript2.0

I recently installed nodejs v6.9.2 via https://nodejs.org
I try to update packages in cmd but it looks no change at all. I was able to change npm version with these commands, somethings wrong with nodejs in my pc..
Here is output:

[image]

How can I fix it

EDITED:
here is npm and node version outputs.
[image]

Comment: check version using node -v

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I update npm on Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26908899/how-do-i-update-npm-on-windows)

Comment: @NileshSingh man I already tried that cant solve my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way of upgrade NPM on Windows:https://github.com/felixrieseberg/npm-windows-upgrade

Open windows power shell with Administrator access

```
npm install -g npm-windows-upgrade
npm-windows-upgrade
```

Do not run npm i -g npm. Instead use npm-windows-upgrade to update npm going forward. Also if you run the NodeJS installer, it will replace the node version.

Comment: Ty for answer it looks valueable but why this comands shows 4.1.1 as latest version of npm I already installed 6.9.2. how can I update it to this version. "npm-windows-upgrade --npm-version 6.9.2" not works