# Npm updates sucessfully, but still shows old version

Tags: npm

When I do a `npm -v` I see that I am still on 5.6.0. And keep getting prompts to do a `npm i npm`.

But I've done a `sudo npm install npm@latest -g` and double checked with a `npm outdated -g --depth=0` to see that my global npm is at the latest already (6.0.0).

How do I resolve this conflict? Is the npm I'm using the latest or is it still the old one? Is it because my global is linked incorrectly or something?

Comment: Also encountering same problem here, has u been able to solve this?

Comment: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50529037/npm-global-not-being-used/50752841#50752841

Comment: I had the same problem and once I logged out of the terminal and logged back in all was good.

Comment: Previously answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26908899/how-do-i-update-npm-on-windows/26908900#26908900

Comment: @StephenPham seems like it's a windows solution. No love for Macs? =(

Comment: Try restarting your computer if you haven't already, or try `npm i npm --save`. Either of these could work.

Comment: are you in windows or mac? if it's windows, you should install it outside WSL. If it's on mac, check if you are updating in your local

Answer (score 45):

**Try closing the Terminal - once you open it again it should work, worked for me well.**

*IvanD wrote this solution in a comment to the original post, I thought it's worth an answer post.

Comment: Thought I'd just add closing and opening, logging out and back in, shutting off and on the computer doesn't solve this issue. Apparently there was some hard pathing/aliasing issue happening. Only uninstalling and reinstalling node worked.

Answer (score 34):

I can 100% vouch this works.

I got this from someone who teaches node.js.

Give NVM (Node Version Manager) a try.  Do the commands in the following ordrer:

1. curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.11/install.sh | bash
2. command -v nvm
3. nvm install node

finally confirm that the update was successful

4. npm -v

Comment: This is perfect solutions, you save my day

Comment: My pleasure :o)

Comment: happy to help you.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: My Mac M1 now work!/Thanks

Comment: In my case, a reboot was needed after the first step so that nvm command could be used. I'm in ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 27):

Let's do a better solution if all of the mention methods not help you:

You need to install `nvm` ([Node Version Manager](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm))

After that just run:

```
nvm install 14
```

list your versions to see is version installed

```
nvm ls
```

and you will get list like this:

```
        v10.2.0
       v12.18.3
->     v14.10.0
         system
default -> 14.10.0 (-> v14.10.0)
node -> stable (-> v14.10.0) (default)
stable -> 14.10 (-> v14.10.0) (default)
iojs -> N/A (default)
unstable -> N/A (default)
lts/* -> lts/erbium (-> v12.18.3)
lts/argon -> v4.9.1 (-> N/A)
lts/boron -> v6.17.1 (-> N/A)
lts/carbon -> v8.17.0 (-> N/A)
lts/dubnium -> v10.22.0 (-> N/A)
lts/erbium -> v12.18.3
```

Switch default version like this:

```
nvm alias default 14.10.0
```

And check:

```
node -v
```

If print `v14.10.0` you are ready to rock, if not:

```
nvm use 14
```

and check again.

This need to work like a charm and you will be happy.

Comment: This was so helpful and it worked. Thanks

Comment: Tried multiple approaches to install the latest version(s), All got successfully installed, Still the `node -v` call was pointing to the old version 16.X instead of my expectation 18.X. The `nvm use 18` helped me. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 9):

Check your `/usr/local/lib` folder. I had the same problem and a `node_modules` folder in here. After removing it and rerunning `[sudo] npm install npm@latest -g` it showed and used the correct version.

Answer (score 7):

```
sudo npm install -g n
```

If you want latest stable version

```
sudo n stable
```

If you want the latest version

```
sudo n latest
```

Then restart computer

Comment: I tried the command you mentioned and as it did before, it does say that it has updated 1 package and it's now + npm@6.0.0 but when I do a npm -v command, i see that it is still 5.6.0. So I'm quite confused as it always is able to update without errors, but upon checking -v it is still the old verison.

Comment: i had same problem, restart was all I had to do.

Comment: This shouldn't be downvoted... nobody mentioned that you need to restart your computer to get it to apply the changes. +1

Comment: Just log out and log in again!

Comment: @jscul restarting, logging out and in, closing and opening terminal, all these didn't work as there was a pathing/aliasing issue that caused this for me. Only a full uninstall of node worked.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue today with Node installer node-v10.16.0-x64.msi. Even after installing it I got the node version from npm -v as 3.10... and my react app would fail to start :(

It seems that node creates a folder in APPDATA at %AppData%\Roaming\npm 
There was an old npm.exe lying there and this was in my Windows Path at user level. The user level Path overrides the system level Path where the new installer had added its path. The user override caused the new npm to not be found. Solution: Shift-Delete %AppData%\Roaming\npm !  :D Remove and reinstall with node-v10.16.0-x64.msi

Now npm -v gives 6.9.0!

Comment: yea, it seems that uninstalling/installing is the way to solve this, other attempts are all futile for me too

Answer (score 2):

**Problem summary**

```sh
npm -v # 6.xx
npm install npm@latest -g
npm -v # still the same, but should be 7.xx
```

**Solution** based on the answer of fypnlp.

```sh
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.11/install.sh | bash
```

The terminal now wants to configure some `~/.zshrc` file which I don't have on my Mac yet. So let’s create it

```sh
nano ~/.zshrc
```

and paste

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
```

Now restart the terminal and run

```sh
command -v nvm # should return "nvm"
nvm install node
npm -v # now it’s 7.xx yay!
```

Comment: ```nvm install node``` worked for me. Thanks for it

Answer (score 1):

If you have tried all the mentioned approach like :-
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable

or

sudo npm install npm@latest -g 
still npm -v showing you the older version, once try to close your terminal and open a new one and check.

Answer (score 1):

Though this is an old question and the answer might not be relevant but I found myself into such situation many time, sometimes restarting the server is not a solution because other process will get effected. So you need to refresh the terminal without actually restarting the server and for that you may run `exec bash` and that will certainly help.

Answer (score 1):

I found this command line that worked for me.

Update from version `12.18` to the latest version `15.2` correctly.

I hope this is useful:

```
nvm install node --reinstall-packages-from=node
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue. I had node v14.15.4 installed on ubuntu 18, but when i used `node -v` it showed v11.0.0.
To check all the node versions available on your system using nvm, use

```
nvm ls
```

To set the newly installed node version as the default, use

```
nvm alias default <version>
```

Then, just close the terminal and open a new terminal to check the node version.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is [replecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237295/how-can-i-update-node-js-and-npm-to-the-next-versions) and already has an answer.
First, The LTS and current version of NPM is 5.6.0 for both Node 8.11.1 (LTS) and Node 10.0.0 (Latest current version) according to the official [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237295/how-can-i-update-node-js-and-npm-to-the-next-versions).

Otherwise, `sudo npm install npm@latest -g` should install the latest version NPM globally.

Comment: I've already done sudo npm install npm@latest -g and on my terminal it does say that updated package to +npm6.0.0, but as I mentioned in the initial question when I do a npm -v, I again see that it is 5.6.0.

Answer (score 0):

Search for a node_modules folder in your home directory, rename it or delete it, then try again.

Answer (score 0):

1. First uninstall your installed nodejs from Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Programs and Features.
2. Delete nodejs folder from the Program Files (x86) folder.
3. Now install new version and check it once.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same error today.Updated npm version does not reflect.

This is how I resolved it.

1. A lot of post suggested to use the command npm cache clean --f. But, it did not work for me. Hence, I deleted the "npm" and "npm-cache" folders from the location C:\Users\SearchYourUserName\AppData\Roaming
2. Uninstalled the existing node.
3. Re-Installed node version v10.x.x. I downloaded the node-v10.22.1-x64.msi file from https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/ and installed it.

Then checked the npm version. It had worked.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this could be happening due to mistakes like you installing packages using `yarn` ex:

```
// update the version number in package.json then
yarn install
```

and trying to run scripts using `npm` like

```
npm run start
```

Actually I did this mistake.
So make sure to use either `yarn` or `npm`, but not both.

Answer (score 0):

I have this same symptom but none of the answers helped and I finally found the issue.
It may not be exactly the same as the OP's but I think it is along the same lines. @Kelvin Zhao's solution of un-installing and re-installing worked for him but not for me so this might be useful for others.

My issue ended up being that I use brew and (I can't remember how exactly) but I seem to be have an old version in the brew Celler.
Brew didn't know about it, or couldn't tell me as I do a `brew uninstall node` and it says its doesn't exist.
When I run `node -v` or `npm -v` I get the old versions.

I uninstalled and reinstalled using `brew` and `npm` and `sudo npm` etc didn't do it. it showed the correct versions being installed but `node -v` still showed the old.

Turns out there is a version in my `/usr/local/Celler` directory named `node@14`.

So running `brew uninstall node@14` got rid of that and now node -v doesn't work anymore.

Now re-installing node works. `brew install node`

---

More info for further details for those interested.

I wanted to find out where I still had node installed so I did `echo $PATH` as it had to be somewhere in the path else `node -v` wouldn't be recognised.

Turns out I had `/usr/local/opt/node@14` in my path (which linked to `/usr/local/Celler/node@14`)

That is how I found it.
And now I think I remember how it got there. I'm 90% sure that I did an upgrade of node and brew asked what to do with the old version and I think I said to keep it.
And that was my mistake that lead me here (and where I think OP's situation differs)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I wanted to use Version 18 and it was showing 16. I'm using homebrew on my mac and the command that worked for me was the following:

```
brew uninstall node@16
```

And voila the version that was showing after is 18.

Answer (score 0):

I had issue with VS Code when I did nvm alias in its own terminal, even after ran alias command, the version kept switching back to old version even I open a new terminal within the VS Code. But as stupid as it sounds, close and reopen the vscode for me worked, **after** I set the version in an independent terminal.