# Npm global not being used?

Tags: node.js, npm

So I've previously had some npm issues and followed some stackoverflow/github issues commands to attempt to fix them. Which worked... Kinda. Everything was fine until recently when I realised that my global npm packages are not actually being read/used.

So whenever I did a npm -g install xxx, or an update. It updates the global folder alright, but it's just not being used. So I went to dig a little and found this.

Where npm is reading/using from

```
usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

Where the global is installing to

```
Users/Me/.npm-global/lib/node_modules
```

So whenever I did a -g check for my modules and stuff, everything is good and updated, but when I actually try to run anything, the npm command uses the one in the older folders. So basically I can't update or install anything using -g. And nothing goes into the old folder which is the one being actually used.

How do I resolve this? Was some linking or profile got screwed?

Comment: Please add the output of `npm config list`, `env` and `alias` commands in your question

Comment: What's the command for env and alias?

Comment: They themselves are bash commands not npm

Comment: Ah, I'm not too sure how to run those bash commands.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like this is about your npm prefix configuration.
Global Prefix is the folder where npm will install global packages.

First I would run the following command to get the value of the global prefix (https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/prefix)

```
$ npm prefix -g
```

To set it to a different value:

```
npm config set prefix /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

This is for the location of your global packages, now you need to check that your terminal PATH variable is checking this folder for binaries.

```
$ echo $PATH
```

Command above will print a ":" separated list of folder location that your shell checks for binaries.

Your global npm prefix location should be part of that list, from your question I'd assume this folder /usr/local/lib/node_modules already is.

Comment: When I try to run the second command you suggested, it prompts the following errors
npm ERR! Usage:
npm ERR! npm config set <key> <value>
npm ERR! npm config get [<key>]
npm ERR! npm config delete <key>
npm ERR! npm config list [--json]
npm ERR! npm config edit
npm ERR! npm set <key> <value>
npm ERR! npm get [<key>]
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! alias: c

Comment: My bad I just fixed it

Comment: I ran the new command, there isn't any errors but the results seems the same, /Users/Kelvin/.npm-packages/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin which is what I got previously, is this correct?

Comment: I see --global seems to be the problem can you try without it (edit)

Comment: Tried the new command, this is the results of the echo, /Users/Kelvin/.npm-packages/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
When I check the prefix, it does point to the usr/local now. Hmm... Wondering if this means it's fixed. But Users/Kelvin will always be in the echo? It's still being used?

Comment: Oops, now npm list -g --depth=0 shows (empty) /usr/local/lib/node_modules/lib
└── (empty)

Comment: I think I accidentally screwed things up even more. I tried changing back, but typed wrongly now even npm prefix -g shows this error Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/node_modules'
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Comment: Try running this command 
`sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/lib/node_modules` to resolve your permission denied issue.

Answer (score 2):

Below are the steps to change the home directory for global npm installations for currently logged in user:

1. Make a directory for global installations:

   `mkdir ~/.npm-global`
2. Configure npm to use the new directory path:

   `npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'`
3. Open or create a ~/.profile file and add this line:

   `export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH`
4. Back on the command line, update your system variables:

   `source ~/.profile`
5. Test: Download a package globally without using sudo.

   `npm install -g <package_name>`

Instead of steps 1-5, you can use the corresponding ENV variable (e.g. if you don't want to modify ~/.profile):

```
NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=~/.npm-global
```

The above configuration would not work if you use sudo to install the npm modules as it will follow the configurations set for root user.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. But I think those are the few steps in the first place that caused some of the linking issues. But anyways, after trying all the different answers in this thread my npm was down for a few days so in the end I had to delete everything completely and use nvm instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to respect the order of load.

> ## [Loading from `node_modules` Folders](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders)
>
> If the module identifier passed to `require()` is not a
>   core module, and does not begin
>   with `'/'`, `'../'`, or
>   `'./'`, then Node.js starts at the parent directory
>   of the current module, and adds `/node_modules`, and
>   attempts to load the module from that location. Node will not append
>   `node_modules` to a path already ending in
>   `node_modules`.
>
> If it is not found there, then it
>   moves to the parent directory, and so on, until the root of the file
>   system is reached.
>
> For example, if the file at
>   `'/home/ry/projects/foo.js'` called
>   `require('bar.js')`, then Node.js would look in the
>   following locations, in this order:
>
> - `/home/ry/projects/node_modules/bar.js`
> - `/home/ry/node_modules/bar.js`
> - `/home/node_modules/bar.js`
> - `/node_modules/bar.js`
>
> This allows
>   programs to localize their dependencies, so that they do not
>   clash.
>
> It is possible to require specific files or sub modules
>   distributed with a module by including a path suffix after the module
>   name. For instance
>   `require('example-module/path/to/file')` would
>   resolve `path/to/file` relative to where
>   `example-module` is located. The suffixed path follows the
>   same module resolution semantics.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. But after trying all the different answers in this thread my npm was down for a few days so in the end, I had to delete everything completely and use nvm instead

Answer (score 0):

Just a littler change on maxletou's answer, did you try setting prefix as follows?

```
npm config set prefix /usr/local
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, what l did was check the prefix `npm config list` and the prefix was set to: prefix="/Users/nameofuser/.npm-global" and l set the prefix to prefix ="/usr/local/bin" by typing out `npm config set prefix/usr/local` and everything is working as it should.