# Unable to upgrade npm to npm@latest Mac

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install

I'm on MacBook Air HighSierra v10.13.4.

I installed node from https://nodejs.org/ and it gave me `npm@5.6.0`.
I want to upgrade npm to the current lastest version.

So I've tired  `npm i npm@latest -g` , `npm i npm -g` and `sudo npm i npm -g`. 
It returns

```
/Users/sandeep/.npm-global/bin/npm -> /Users/sandeep/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
/Users/sandeep/.npm-global/bin/npx -> /Users/sandeep/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npx-cli.js
+ npm@6.4.0
updated 1 package in 12.452s
```

But no good when I run `npm -v` it returns me `5.6.0`.

But when i run `npm list --depth=0 -g` it shows `npm@6.4.0`.

Can someone pls help me with this ?

Comment: Which node version are you using?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50092693/npm-updates-sucessfully-but-still-shows-old-version

Comment: Can you type `which npm`?

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50529037/npm-global-not-being-used/50752841#50752841

Comment: node v8.11.3 @connexo

Comment: 8.11.4 was current a week ago already, so it seems you have downloaded it some time ago? Also, current MacOS is 10.13.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will suggest you download [macOS Installer node-v8.11.4.pkg](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) and use your installer to install it.

**Node**: On default ***Latest LTS Version: 8.11.4 (includes npm 5.6.0)***

After you install the default *8.11.4*, run:

```
npm install -g npm
```

This should update you to the most recent version of npm.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can upgrade to the latest version of npm using:

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

Or upgrade to the most recent release:

```
npm install -g npm@next
```

You may need to prefix these commands with `sudo`, especially on **Linux**, or **OS X** if you installed Node using its default installer.

Comment: If you need sudo, it's almost certain you installed it the wrong way. I'd recommend using nvm (Node version manager) to install, update and manage your node installation.

Comment: @connexo how do i go it with nvm

Comment: https://github.com/creationix/nvm